# TileMap in android

Tags: android, tiles

I can´t find a solution to my problem. I tiled an Image and saved it into an Bitmap Array. Now I want to fill it into a 7 x 7 grid. I need to do it because I want to access and maybe change the single tiles. I tried Gridview but it seems like I just can set the columns, not the rows.

Isnt there a Tile Map Class for Android that can easily access the cells of it and assign different pictures to it?

I know I should show some code but all I did is searching what to do with my Bitmap Array.

Any Idea how to solve this?

thanks a lot, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such class.  But you can easily create your own view that maintains an internal grid and paints to its canvas with that grid in mind.  Study [TileView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.html) from the Snake SDK example.